# Python Visual Studio Code cannot find module

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm importing `debugpy` into my code and it works, but VSCode complains that it cannot be imported:

[image]

The interpreter shows that I am in the same venv as my terminal:

[image]

In my terminal (in VSCode) I can list `debugpy` and import it at the Python prompt.

```sh
(python4uvm_examples) raysalemi@RayProMac python4uvm_examples % pip list | grep debugpy
debugpy           1.4.1
(python4uvm_examples) raysalemi@RayProMac python4uvm_examples % python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  4 2020, 02:22:02) 
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import debugpy
>>>
```

How do I get VSCode to see that it can be imported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they have this bug for some time now. what I do - select another interpreter, then re-select the one I need. usually works. (using Pylance as language server).

Comment: Aha! That's what happened. Yes it started working after I was poking around.